# LocalRunHelper.exe doesn't refresh resource file in ScopeWorkDir

Tags: azure-data-lake

it seems that I have to delete resource file (referenced by DEPLOY RESOURCE) myself in that folder in order to refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the LocalRunHelper.exe does not overwrite your deployed recourse file between 2 local submission?

If so, we will file a bug for this.